# How do I debug/handle Firebase App Check Invalid Requests?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-app-check

I've integrated (but not enforced) App Check within an iOS app of mine, and have a number of requests that are apparently invalid - that is, the requests have an invalid App Check token. I am using Apple's App Attest as the Attestation Provider.

The two example reasons given for this occurring are

1. "inauthentic client attempting to impersonate your app"
2. "from emulated environments"

I don't think 1 is happening, because I have a tiny user base (< 10 active users). I also don't think 2 is happening. I very rarely use emulated environments; I prefer building and testing on a physical device.

From troubleshooting on my own, it seems like the issue has to do with me using a debug build on my physical device vs a release build. I followed the instructions here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/debug-provider, and the errors have apparently dropped to zero for the last 24 hours.

I have two questions:

1. Is this conclusion correct? That is, is it possible that me using a debug build is what was causing all those unverified requests? The two examples given don't mention anything about a physical device, so I'm not sure if this conclusion is right.
2. If the answer to 1 is yes, what is the correct workflow setup I should be using? It seems like the debug tokens have the same TTL as the normal App Check tokens (i.e. 1 hour), and manually uploading a token every 1 hour while developing doesn't seem scalable. Is it possible to have the debug tokens have a longer TTL? Or is it possible to upload these tokens through code vs having to manually add via the firebase console?

Answer (score 2):

Firebaser here!

A debug build of your App should fail App Check, part of the verification is that a legitimate device is running a production build of your app.  In that regard it is intended and expected.

Using [Debug Tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/debug-provider) is the correct approach, the debug token itself *will never expire* but will be exchanged for an App Check token which will expire in 1 hour or whatever you have your TTL set as by the App Check SDK.

Comment: Thanks for this response, I was also wondering why my requests were showing as "unverified" when I followed the documentations. I hope Firebase would allow proper testing when we are using "real device" in simulated/development environment though.

Comment: You have to generate a new debug token. if the AppAttest tokens are set to TTL 1 hour, then your debug token will TTL 1 hour too.